# MIP SDK Java Wrapper Sample Crashed With Core Dump

Tags: java, microsoft-information-protection, azure-information-protection, mip-sdk

I'm trying out [this sample application](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/MipSDK-File-Java-Basic) in a Ubuntu 20.04 VM to decrypt an AIP protected office file using MIP SDK. For the application's dependency, I'm using MIP SDK Java Wrapper version 1.12.101 as that seems to be the only version available on [Microsoft website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=104794).

I was able to get it to decrypt some protected files successfully. However, the application can randomly crash with core dump. The crash does not seem to occur with a predictable frequency. Sometimes it happens right after I start the application, sometimes it crashes after having been able to decrypt a hundred protected files or so.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fefe2b6fd46, pid=2721553, tid=2721672
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (15.0.2+7) (build 15.0.2+7-27)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (15.0.2+7-27, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libpthread.so.0+0xdd46]  pthread_rwlock_wrlock+0x16
#
# Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/share/apport/apport -p%p -s%s -c%c -d%d -P%P -u%u -g%g -- %E" (or dumping to /home/user/RMS_WORK/MIP/mip-sdk-nl-latest/mip-nl-sdk-test/core.2721553)
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

I am not sure what the error seems to be referring to. Any advice on how to proceed would be appreciated.

On a side note, I have tried to created a small test application from the sample application above and run it in a RHEL 8 docker image. The crash also randomly occurs, but the error message is slightly different.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f1cd5b74c00, pid=59, tid=33672
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Red_Hat-17.0.6.0.10-3.el8_7) (17.0.6+10) (build 17.0.6+10-LTS)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Red_Hat-17.0.6.0.10-3.el8_7) (17.0.6+10-LTS, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libmip_file_sdk.so+0x7f1c00]  CPDF_Object::GetType() const+0xc
#
# Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/share/apport/apport -p%p -s%s -c%c -d%d -P%P -u%u -g%g -- %E" (or dumping to /home/jboss/core.59)
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://bugzilla.redhat.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=Red%20Hat%20Enterprise%20Linux%208&component=java-17-openjdk
#
```

I recognize this libmip_file_sdk.so as part of the .so library files in the mip_sdk_file_rhel8_1.12.101.tar.gz I downloaded from MIP SDK Microsoft website. Does that mean the crash is caused by the MIP SDK itself?